# Inclusion-Exclusion with 4 sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

At MEXICANO tourism club, tourists can mix and match different activities while visiting Mexico. There are 49 tourists visiting Hel-Ha Park (H), 61 tourists visiting Pyramid of Tenochtitlan (T), 52 tourists visiting Chichen Itsa (C), and 28 visiting the National Museum of Anthropology (M). There are exactly 20 tourists for any two of these visits, 10 tourists for any three of them and 5 taking all of them. Using inclusion-exclusion, calculate how many tourists are doing at least one or more visits.

ANSWER = 105

---

I don't understand why the answer to this question is 105. 
To me it should be 190 - 20 + 10 - 5 = 175

Comment: (M) must be 38 and not 28, right?

Comment: No, 28 is correct.

Comment: Why do you think it is 190 - 20 + 10 - 5?

Answer (score 3):

As there are $20$ tourists taking each pair of visits, the subtraction for two cases hould be $6 \cdot 20$ as there are ${4 \choose 2}=6$ pairs of visits that can be taken.  Similarly the addition for three visits should be ${4 \choose 3} \cdot 10=40$ as the people who visited three things got counted three times in the single visit case and subtracted three times in the two visit case, so need to be added once.  The count should be $190-6\cdot 20+4\cdot 10-5=105$

Comment: Can you please check the vann diagram below? What part of the question did I get wrong? (Note that my vann diagram considers (M) to be $38$ and not $28$ because according to the drawing it seems impossible, it must have at least $30$ according to the given)

Comment: @LO2A:  My figure of $190$ comes from $M=28$ and adding the other three numbers of visitors.  I agree that the input data is inconsistent.  Once you show that any combination of more than one attraction has $5$ visitors you should subtract $35$, not $30$ from the number of visitors  to each attraction to get the number that visited that attraction alone.  I didn't check your Venn (not vann) diagram, but with four sets you are missing some regions.  You can't make one with circles with over three criteria.

Comment: Okay then the input data is inconsistent, but can you please explain why it is not possible to draw a Venn diagram with $4$ sets? I think I didn't miss any region, I would like you to check it out if it is possible, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't look closely, but your diagram looks like the non-example on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).  It points out the two regions that are missing.  I think that is where the difference of $5$ to subtract comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Each $3$ visits are made $10$ tourists, in which $5$ of them make all the $4$ visits. Similarly each $2$ visits are made by $20$ tourists in which $15$ make either all the visits or $3$ of them. So there are exactly $5$ tourists for any of $2$ visits ONLY (i.e. doesn't do $3$ visits).

I think now you can draw a [venn diagram](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vbqd1pm79r), those that visit ONLY (H) are $19$, ONLY (T) $31$, ONLY (C) $22$, ONLY (M) must be $8$ (if you adjust the number from $28$ to $38$)